# Why use genitive case in "Я был дома"?

Tags: грамматика

I encountered a sentence: `Я был дома.`. However, the sentence uses `дома`, the genitive form of a noun `дом`. But I cannot understand why the genitive is used in this case.

Specifically, why not say `Я был дом.`? Isn't it that the genitive is used in a sentence in which a negation occurs?

Comment: if you would use `Я был дом` it would have a meaning of `I was a house`, while `Я был дома` means `I was at home`. But why all this happens I cannot tell you definitely. The only thing I remember from the school is that `дома` in this case is (I don't know the correct terms for the next items in English) `обстоятельство` (a circumstance) which is `второстепенный член предложения` (a subordinate member of a sentence) and must be always in an indirect case. For me it is obvious and what I'm used to, but it is hard to explain from the scientific point.

Comment: @user907860 Thanks. But then why is a prepositional such as `на` or `в` not used? I cannot get when you use a prepositional and when you use only genitive... And what is "indirect case"?

Comment: the indirect case is any case, except nominative.

Comment: the word `дом` has at least two meanings, which are `a house, a home, a building` and `home` (in its broader sense, that is one's place of living, a place where one come from etc.). If you use a preposition `на, в, перед, под, к` etc. then the meaning will be the first one `a house`. I would not vouch for the 100% correctness, but I think that the only preposition which is used with `дом` in the second meaning (`home` in its broader sense) is `из` (`from`), when you say `из дому`. But if you say `из дома` (with A at the end) then the word has the first meaning (a house)

Comment: in your example `Я был дома` it has the second meaning, that is `I was at home`

Comment: @Blaszard, this is just an exceptional situation to memorize: дома means "at home" and don't try to find some broad grammatical reason for it.  Well, of course if you want to say "two houses" it is два дома, and there дома doesn't mean "at home." But if you want to someone is "at home" then you say the person is дома.

Comment: also I can suggest a good analogy with English. When you tell someone to return to his home, you don't say `go to home`, you say `go home`. So, I think, such things should be just memorized

Comment: actually, there is not so much to memorize with the word `дом` - home (not a house, a building etc). You can be at home - `дома` (not at home - `не дома`). You can be moving home - `домой` (not home - `не домой`). And you can be moving from home - `из дому` (not from home - `не из дому`). That is only three items.

Comment: @user907860 and KCd, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Blaszard You might have been confused because you saw  prepositional case used in such situations: `Я был в деревне, Я был в лесу.` Similarly, one can say: `Я был в доме.` - `I was in a house.` As opposed to the backyard.

Comment: cf. I was in a house / I was at home. Why 'at'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no applied case for any grammatical case at all. It is adverb, at least, from our Grammarians.

> Главным формальным признаком *наречия* как части речи является
>   отсутствие словоизменения.

`дома, там, вчера, вместе, вдвоем, ...` — are all adverbs

For example, in the phrase:

```
   noun    adv
  встреча вечером
  дорога  домой
```

see more: http://rusgram.narod.ru/1645-1668.html

Answer (score 5):

***Дома*** - is the remnant form of the old Russian Local case(местный падеж)  which has not been retained in modern Russian.

In modern Russian such forms are considered to be adverbs.

See: "Морфология русского литературного языка. Наречие. Форма и значение наречий" (№ 36/2004 газеты "Русский язык" издательского дома "Первое сентября")
UPD ***По мнению Макса Фасмера, форма "дома" ("Я дома") является древней формой местного падежа. Реже эту форму определяют как форму Р.п., однако это маловероятно, так как историческим окончанием Р.п. слов склонения на -у, в которое входило слово "дом", было окончание -у (например, "из дому").
См.: Фасмер М. Этимологический словарь русского языка: в 4 т. Изд. 3-е. Т. 1 (А - Д). СПб., 1996. С. 526-527.***

Comment: Местный падеж в данном случае "дому", а не "дома". Наречий от местного падежа хватает - вверху, внизу, долу, горе и т.п. Но здесь не тот случай.

Comment: user4419802, первоначально у местного падежа была беспредложная форма, которая сейчас полностью утрачена. См.: "Морфология русского литературного языка. Наречие. Форма и значение наречий" (№ 36/2004 газеты "Русский язык" издательского дома "Первое сентября")

Comment: @Серж "дома" — это не местный падеж, тем не менее, а очень древний творительный. как "вчера" от "вечер". могу путать, но газете вашей что-то верю меньше, чем себе.

Comment: В другой статье написано, что наречие дома образовалось от родительного падежа существительного дом.

Comment: Наречия же образованные от творительного падежа имеют следующие окончания: ***-ом/-ем/-ой/-ей/-ами/-ями.***

Comment: Интересно сравнить с сочетанием "***у*** *дома*", вкупе с эквивалентностью русского предлога "*в*" с украинским "*у*" (или я ошибаюсь?)

Comment: Насчет украинского не понял.

Answer (score 1):

I too was looking for answer to the same question: why "I'm at home" would be translated "я дома" with дом in the genitive as opposed to maybe with a preposition, like "я на доме" or "я в доме". I guess sometimes you just have to accept that that's the way it's said and that's what it means. Really, that's how all children learn their native language. Everything is taught by repetition and only after a good few years of learning to use the language by trial and error can one then reflect back on the why's of it all.

Comment: The oblique form of **вечер** that led to **вчера** is believed to be a very old instrumental (of all things). Could that be the case with **дома** as well? **Doma** also exists in Czech and doesn't match any regular case form at all (the genitive is **domu**).

Answer (score -1):

because your house is your home and your home is a house (or mostly).

дом -> (a) house/home

- where are you? -> где ты?

- at a house -> в доме
- at home -> дома (this is the prepositional way to say AT HOME in Russian, not any genitive form)

as some people have already explained, it has nothing to do with Домой, they are not interchangeable because they don't have the same meaning (when it comes to the case they belong to) this last one would be the accusative form of дома.

- where are you going to? -> куда ты идешь?

- I am going to a house -> Я иду в дом
- I am going home -> Я иду домой