Why is this use of a genitive correct in this sentence
Found this in a textbook and confirmed it using an AI translator:
"Мы были дома"
Why is the genitive form дома used here. I've looked in the few books I have and nothing explains this usage.

https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/9493/why-use-genitive-case-in-Я-был-дома?rq=1
